# I am trying to output portfolio items with a picture. This code doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: custom-post-types, themes, templates

```
<?php 
  $temp = $wp_query; 
  $wp_query = null; 
  $wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
 $wp_query->query('showposts=21&post_type=portfolio'.'&paged='.$paged); 
$count = 0; 
 while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
?>
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="boxx artistboxx one-third column <?
 php if ($count == 0) { echo 'alpha'; } ?> <?php if ($count == 2) { echo 
'omega'; } ?>">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
<img src="<?php $key="image"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?>" 
class="video-image" />
<span><?php the_title(); ?></span></a>
</div>
<?php if ($count == 2) { echo '<div class="clearfix"></div>'; $count = 0; } 
else 
$count++; ?>    
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php 
$wp_query = null; 
$wp_query = $temp;  // Reset
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to show the 'featured image'? Or can you use it?
If so, there is a simple way to do it:

Add this line of code in your theme’s **functions.php** file, or be sure that it has this:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

Add this line where you want to show the image:

```
the_post_thumbnail();
```

Following what you seem to be doing, that is, using a meta field, try to put in a variable before echoing, sometimes it helps me spoting another problems in the code. Ex:

```
$key_1_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true);
echo $key_1_value;
```

Comment: Oh my god, you just solved the problem, and the thing that was wrong was very stupid - I was not using meta on this website at all, I copied the code from one of my other sites, not realising that it wasn't utilising the regular thumbnails. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Glad I could help =)